# What will be value of $\vec{r} \cdot \nabla$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was studying on Nabla Operator and saw that $\nabla \cdot \vec{r} \neq \vec{r} \cdot \nabla$

So, if I were to find $\vec{r} \cdot \nabla$ how would I calculate it?

I know that $\vec{r} \cdot \nabla$ = $r_1 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + r_2 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + r_3 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

but what I'm confused is on what am i suppose to differentiate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions $\vec r\cdot \nabla$,  $\vec r\times \nabla$, etc. are operators.

Thus, if $\Phi$ is a scalar field and $\vec F$ is a vector field, then

$$(\vec r\cdot \nabla)(\Phi)=\sum_i x_i \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}$$

is a scalar

$$(\vec r\cdot \nabla)(\vec F)=\sum_i x_i \frac{\partial \vec F}{\partial x_i}$$

is a vector

$$(\vec r\times \nabla)(\Phi)=\sum_i \sum_j (x_i\hat x_i\times \hat x_j) \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_j}$$

is a vector

$$(\vec r\times \nabla)(\vec F)=\sum_i \sum_j (x_i\hat x_i\times \hat x_j) \frac{\partial \vec F}{\partial x_j}$$

is a tensor.

Comment: Here, symbols with arrows are vectors.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that $\nabla \cdot \textbf{r}$ is a scalar, but $\textbf{r}\cdot \nabla$ is another *operator.*  You're not going to get a scalar from this latter quantity unless you act it on a scalar field.

Comment: Could you tell me how is $\vec{r} \cdot \nabla$ defined?

Comment: @rndflas The way you wrote it in your prompt is correct.  It simply is $\textbf{r}\cdot \nabla = r_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + r_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial y} + r_3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

Comment: It might be stupid question but to what am i suppose to differentiate? i mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of what??

Comment: @rndflas Computing $\textbf{r}\cdot \nabla$ doesn't yield a quantity, it yields another operator.  You can apply your new operator to any differentiable scalar field.  For example, $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ is one such function.  You won't get a function from this, but it can be applied to a function of the form I mentioned.

Comment: Of _whatever_ comes next.  Take some scalar field, $f(x,y,z)$, then $$(\vec r \cdot \nabla) f(x,y,z) = r_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x,y,z) + r_j\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y,z) + r_k\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,y,z) $$